# Gmail keyboard shortcut to "expand all"?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to "Expand all" emails in a conversation after having navigated via <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd>? Typing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd> doesn't do much.

Comment: I'm looking for this too

Comment: User also post on Gmail product site http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/dM9jadRIjOA

Comment: I just created a [Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-expand-all-keyboard/ciocgdpejlhegbegfjlfhjgjgbfcjkgb?hl=en&gl=JP) to do this. Alt+A is the shortcut.

Comment: Semicolon ";" now provides the "expand all" feature and colon ":" collapses all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a keyboard shortcut for this.

You can use <kbd>n</kbd> (Next message) or <kbd>p</kbd> (previous message) to navigate up and down the conversation tree. You can then use <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to expand an individual message that is part of a conversation.

<sub>[Resource: Gmail Keyboard Shortcuts](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6594)</sub>

Comment: I don't see why not having a hotkey for expand/collapse all

Comment: ; and : are now the default keyboard shortcuts for expand/collapse all. see your settings at https://mail.google.com/mail/u/#settings/shortcuts

Answer (score 12):

As per comments, once you enabled `Keyboard shortcuts on` in `mail > Settings`, you can use `;` for "expand entire conversation" and `:` for "collapse entire conversation". This and more shortcuts: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en

Original: There is a "custom keyboard shortcut" feature you can enable in labs through Gmail > Settings. Once enabled you can use ";" for "expand all" and ":" for "collapse all" or setup other shortcut you want to use instead.

Comment: this may have been promoted up out of labs into "normal" mail. now all i need is to choose "keyboard shortcuts on" in the general tab of settings, and then semicolon works.  semicolon is listed on a help page here, under "actions": https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594

Comment: Someone should turn @pestophagous's comment into an answer!

Comment: Wow! `;` will be my new favorite shortcut! https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594

Answer (score 3):

There is a Chrome extension that does this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-expand-all-keyboard/ciocgdpejlhegbegfjlfhjgjgbfcjkgb?hl=en&gl=JP

Answer (score 0):

To expand the conversation list, follow the step:

1. Press <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd> as the case may be to select a conversation.
2. Press <kbd>O</kbd> to open the list which will have the oldest and newest conversation expanded and rest collapsed.
3. Press <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>p</kbd> and you will notice that it selects the number against a collapsed conversation.
4. Press <kbd>o</kbd> to open the conversation.
5. Use <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>p</kbd> to navigate.