# How do you expand a conversation in Gmail? (The "o" or "return" don't work!)

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gmail keyboard shortcut to “expand all”?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17280/gmail-keyboard-shortcut-to-expand-all)

Gmail's shortcut reference says

> o or `<Enter>` : Open conversation; collapse/expand conversation

But when I press <kbd>o</kbd> with a conversation open, the pointer is just moving to the last post of the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>o</kbd> just opens the conversation, but it doesn’t expand it. To expand it, you have to navigate it with <kbd>p</kbd>/<kbd>n</kbd> and then <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Does this mean there is no shortcut to expand the ENTIRE conversation? You can expand the ENTIRE conversation by clicking the "expand/collapse all" button right next to the email subject. That's what I'm looking for. The method described above only expand the CURRENT email, not the entire conversation.

Comment: There is a Chrome extension that does this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-expand-all-keyboard/ciocgdpejlhegbegfjlfhjgjgbfcjkgb?hl=en&gl=JP